# HTML DOM Target attribute self

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have quite amount of fields on my registration page, but the error message will display only on the top of the page, i don wan client keep scroll up to see what is the error message when they key in something wrong on that field. May i know how can i use "target" or any other method for this case?

Here is the example of my screen, the error message was actually display on the top of the screen when user key in something wrong, but user have to scroll up and check the error message, is there any method that i can use to focus/target/scroll up to view the error message? 
[image]

Here is my current screen sample code : `1` [SAMPLE](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/3568)
P/s: i only do function for `username` field, when onblur on the username field it will run the javascript function

Comment: Sounds like ultimately you might like `position:fixed` for your errors (because now the user would have to scroll down again to find the field they made the mistake in).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you set the `location.hash`, it will scroll the page to the element with that `id`.

Example:

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=button]").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("error").style.display = "";
  location.href = "#error";
};
```

```html
<p>Scroll all the way to the bottom</p>
<p id="error" style="display: none">This is the error message</p>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<div>filler</div>
<input type="button" value="Click me">
```

Comment: Hi @T.J. Crowder , thanks for your solution, but for this care ... the validation is not check from the button, it check direct if user key in something wrong.  i was using onblur function.  

`<input name="username" type="text"  id="username"  onblur="fnIC(this.id,this.value);"  />`

Comment: `function fnIC(ID,value){error_function("ERRORMSG",ID,"errMsg")} function error_function(message,ID,labelID)
{document.getElementById(labelID).innerHTML    = message;document.getElementById(labelID).style.display    = "inline";}`

Comment: `<label id="errMsg" target="_self" style="color:red;"></label>`  for label

Answer (score 0):

Without changing any of your HTML, one solution is to add the error message next to the input that has caused the validation error.

You could use floating divs and a myriad of other ways - depending on how you want your errors to be shown, but for now, a message at the point of issue is what I think you want.

Changing your validation function to the following, allows for the message to appear next to the invalid input as it loses focus, and removes it when it is valid. Obviously, you can position it differently and style it as well, but the functionality is here:

```js
var errorLabelSuffix = "ErrorMessage";

function fnIC(ID, value) {
  if (value == "") {
    // Data failed validation...

    // Check if Label is already displayed, and just return if it is.
    if (document.getElementById(ID + errorLabelSuffix)) {
      return;
    }
    // Otherwise, get the parent element of the invalid element (a <p> element at present).
    var invalidElement = document.getElementById(ID).parentNode;
    // Create a <span> to display the error message.
    var errorMessageLabel = document.createElement("span");
    // Give the <span> the Id of the ID passed in along with something to indicate it is the error label.
    errorMessageLabel.id = ID + errorLabelSuffix;
    // Set whatever error message is required.
    errorMessageLabel.innerHTML = "Invalid input";
    // Add the new element to the DOM where the invalid input is.
    invalidElement.appendChild(errorMessageLabel);
    // Can still do this as well (or use it for an error summary).
    error_function("ERRORMSG", ID, "errMsg");
  } else {
    // Has passed validation...

    // Get the input element and its parent.
    var validElement = document.getElementById(ID).parentNode;
    var errorMessageLabel = document.getElementById(ID + errorLabelSuffix);

    // If the error label is already displayed (may not be if the input has always been valid, and still is) - remove it from the DOM.
    if (errorMessageLabel && validElement) {
      validElement.removeChild(errorMessageLabel);
    }
  }
}

function error_function(message, ID, labelID) {
  debugger;
  document.getElementById(labelID).target = "_self";
  document.getElementById(labelID).innerHTML = message;
  document.getElementById(labelID).style.display = "inline";
  document.getElementById(ID).style.background = "#FFCECE";
  document.getElementById(ID).style.border = "thin solid red";
  document.getElementById(ID).value = "";
}
```